# Is the <q> tag same as adding double quotes manually in html?

Tags: html, double-quotes

I have recently started learning html from w3schools.com. In [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_formatting_q) we can add double quotes to any text by using `<q>` tag around it. What I wonder is that we can simply add double quotes manually too, e.g.

`<q>text quoted</q>`

will render just same if we instead add double quotes manually

`"text quoted"`

> - Is there any differnce between these two methods to add double quotes?

Comment: Visually: no difference (assuming you type `“”` instead of just `""`), semantically: yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that when you use the `<q>` element the software reading the page (a browser, a search engine spider, etc) *knows* that it's a quotation and might have different processing rules for it: browsers might render it differently, in italics for example, or a different culture's quote symbols (Japan doesn't use quotes, they use right-angle symbols) and search engines could look-up the quote elsewhere and provide a citation. If you don't mark-up your text then none of these scenarios are possible.

This falls under the umbrella term "the semantic web" - it's about markup throughly describing its content's meaning, not just the way it looks.

Also, don't use W3Schools: they have a poor reputation for teaching only the absolute basics required to achieve and end-goal, often with nasty shortcuts and it instills bad habits. Instead I recommend resources like Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) when learning about the web.

Comment: Thankyou. I guess it is similar to the diff b/w `<b>` and `<strong>`. And yes w3shool didn't explain about simentics diff. Could you tell a better online source for learning html; I already know C language by the way.

Comment: Can you clarify your remark about W3Schools. Just saying "don't use W3Schools" will only serve to confuse the OP.

Comment: The modern world won't wait, while you know every aspect of every language. I would recommend using resources like Mozilla only in difficult cases when you have no idea how to make something work. But for trivial tasks (they take up most of the working time) W3Schools is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The q element represents some phrasing content quoted from another source.
This means we can’t use `<q>` for sarcasm or other non-quotation uses of quote marks (“”). In those cases, add punctuation manually. The spec continues:

For More read the article

http://alistapart.com/article/qtag